# After i install a library in my jupyter notebook, I have an error when importing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, virtual-machine

I am currently in a virtual machine of my faculty that I accessed through ssh, and inside the machine I started a jupyter notebook server. When using jupyter notebook, whenever I try to install a library, any library, I succeed in installing

```
!pip install torch
```

but when I try to import it I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-279c49635b32> in <module>
----> 1 import torch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

I have seen some solutions to similar problems that evolve creating virtual environments, but since I'm inside a virtual machine I don't know if that applies.

Comment: Virtual machine makes no difference at all.  It's exactly like a real system.  However, with Jupyter server, it's easy to get confused about what's running where.  Are you using a browser to access the server?

Comment: Yes, I follow the link provided when I start the server, and open the notebook on a browser

Comment: "I succeed in installing" - You aren't necessarily succeeding in installing to the correct environment. Just somewhere on the machine. The 'ModuleNotFoundError' you see after your supposed successful install is very characteristic of this. Because you don't provide much more of the traceback, I'm not sure it will help here, but you should be using `%pip install` when running inside a Jupyter notebook. The magic variation of this command was added in 2019 to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that is backing the active `.ipynb` in which you run the ...

Comment: <continued> installation. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magic commands `%pip install` and `%conda install`. Use of an exclamation point alone doesn't insure it installs to the correct environment. More at top [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez).  Again, **it may not help here but you'll have a better experience in modern Jupyter going forward using current best practices.**